# Why can't we get consistent results when using spacy to do stemming/lemmatization?

Tags: python, lemmatization, spacy

Here are my python codes:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
line = u'Algorithms; Deterministic algorithms; Adaptive algorithms; Something...'
line = line.lower()
print ' '.join([token.lemma_ for token in nlp(line)])
```

The output is:

```
algorithm ; deterministic algorithm ; adaptive algorithms ; something...
```

Why is the third `algorithms` not converted to 'algorithm'?
And when I remove `lower()` function, I get this:

```
algorithms ; deterministic algorithms ; adaptive algorithm ; something...
```

This time the first and second `algorithms` could not be converted.
This problem drives me crazy, how can I fix this to get every single word to be lemmatized?

Answer (score 2):

What version are you using? With `lower` it works correctly for me:

```
>>> doc = nlp(u'Algorithms; Deterministic algorithms; Adaptive algorithms; Something...'.lower())
>>> for word in doc:
...   print(word.text, word.lemma_, word.tag_)
... 
(u'algorithms', u'algorithm', u'NNS')
(u';', u';', u':')
(u'deterministic', u'deterministic', u'JJ')
(u'algorithms', u'algorithm', u'NNS')
(u';', u';', u':')
(u'adaptive', u'adaptive', u'JJ')
(u'algorithms', u'algorithm', u'NN')
(u';', u';', u':')
(u'something', u'something', u'NN')
(u'...', u'...', u'.')
```

Without the `lower`, the tagger assigns `Algorithms` the tag NNP, i.e. proper noun. This prevents the lemmatisation, because the model has statistically guessed the word is a proper noun.

You can set a special-case rule in the tokenizer to tell spaCy that `Algorithms` is never a proper noun, if you like.

```
from spacy.attrs import POS, LEMMA, ORTH, TAG
nlp = spacy.load('en')

nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case(u'Algorithms', [{ORTH: u'Algorithms', LEMMA: u'algorithm', TAG: u'NNS', POS: u'NOUN'}])
doc = nlp(u'Algorithms; Deterministic algorithms; Adaptive algorithms; Something...')
for word in doc:
    print(word.text, word.lemma_, word.tag_)
(u'Algorithms', u'algorithm', u'NNS')
(u';', u';', u':')
(u'Deterministic', u'deterministic', u'JJ')
(u'algorithms', u'algorithm', u'NN')
(u';', u';', u':')
(u'Adaptive', u'adaptive', u'JJ')
(u'algorithms', u'algorithm', u'NNS')
(u';', u';', u':')
(u'Something', u'something', u'NN')
(u'...', u'...', u'.')
```

The `tokenizer.add_special_case` function allows you to specify how a string of characters will be tokenized, and set attributes on each of the subtokens.

Comment: Thanks, I think this problem may be caused by the version of spacy, I solve this by updating the spacy 1.3.0 to 1.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think syllogism_'s explained it better. But here's another way:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

lemma = WordNetLemmatizer()
line = u'Algorithms; Deterministic algorithms; Adaptive algorithms; Something...'.lower().split(';')
line = [a.strip().split(' ') for a in line]
line = [map(lambda x: lemma.lemmatize(x), l1) for l1 in line ]
print line
```

Output:

```
[[u'algorithm'], [u'deterministic', u'algorithm'], [u'adaptive', u'algorithm'], [u'something...']]
```